# FFT salaries identification over 12 months

Tags: python, pandas, pattern-matching, fft, data-science

**Goal**: Using python I need to be able to identify the income of an individual given their 12 month worth of transactions that have credited their accounts positively.

**Problem**: What steps would i need to take to have a python script identifying the salary or in some cases multiple salaries as a person can have a consistent side job? If there are clearly more than 1 salary payments going in each month, or biweekly, or whatever frequency less than 1 month. I also can't figure out what to set the x axis frequency at if the data i have has a value for every day of the month for the last 12 months so roughly around 365 datapoints.

**Attempted approach**: After doing quite a bit of research it seems that the Fast Fourier Transform is used widely for pattern recognition among sound and other frequency datasets. And i manage to get a diagram which shows pretty clearly the inflow patterns of a chosen user. However i can't figure out *how to have a python script pick out the spikes in the graphs that are clearly repeating every 25-30 days*. In my example the user has 2 sources of income main @ roughly 1500 and second @ 300 per month.

Here's my code for this attempt and some diagrams of the result:

```
#Remove the obviuos outliers from the dataframe
df = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 5).all(axis=1)]
#Get the number of data points in the dataframe 
N = len(df.index.unique())
#frequency of signal (in days)
T = 1
#create x-axis for time length of signal
xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), N)
#create array that corresponds to values in signal
#perform FFT on signal
yf = fft(df)
plt.plot(xf, abs(yf[0:N]))
```

Here's the original dataframe
[image: Original data]
[image: Clear pattern of income flow]

Here's the result i get by applying the FFT code described above. I highlighted the section which to a human eye clearly shows the repeating pattern :)

Comment: what is the question exactly?

Comment: How can i automatically identify the 2 values from the FFT graph. From this example i would expect the output to be 1500 and 300

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scipy.signal.find_peaks` to find the peaks on a slice of your fft array. Since you did not provide the data, I mocked a similar case:

1) I sum up 30 sine waves with random frequency and take the FFT.

2) I select a window of the FFT data and run `fin_peaks` on it

3) I plot the identified peaks

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(11)
x = np.arange(0,1000,0.1)
data = np.array([np.sin(a*x) for a in list(100*np.random.randn(30))])
data_fft = np.fft.fft(np.sum(data, axis=1)) # 1) ends here
plt.plot(np.abs(data_fft))
low_ind, high_ind = 10,20
data_for_peaks = np.abs(data_fft)[low_ind:high_ind]
inds = find_peaks(data_for_peaks)[0] # 2) ends here
plt.plot(low_ind+inds, np.abs(data_fft)[low_ind+inds],'o')
plt.show() # 3) ends here
```

This code produce the following figure

[image]

You can do the same on your data adjusting `low_ind` and `high_ind` to your needs.
Try to run `scipy.signal.find_peaks?` in order to check all the extra argument you can pass: height and width threshold, ratio with respect to otehr peaks etc..

Comment: Do you know how or if i could use find_peaks to identify only the peaks which are occurring at a roughly similar distance from each other and are also of a similar magnitude?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "roughly" and "similar". You need to define a measure for that. With `find_peaks` using the `height` keyword argument you can select a min-max range for your peaks (min and  max can also be arrays) and select peaks with similar magnitude. With the `distance` argument you can set a min distance between the peaks, but not a range. The `prominence` argument put a condition for the ratio between the height and the width of the peak. Try combinations of these k.w.a. and see what works for your case. (please don't forget to accept/upvote the answer if it helped you).

Comment: check all the examples here it might help you https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html